# JPA - enum JOIN (JPQL)

Tags: java, jpa, join, enums, jpql

I've got the following JPQL query:

```
select cio from CadastralIncomeObjection cio where cio.dateInput < :maxValidInputDate and cio.active = true and cio.reasonInValid.valid = false "
        + "and exists (select dd from DocumentDossier dd join dd.documents d where dd.id = cio.id and d.attachmentType = be.ejb.model.entity.admin.option.REPORT)"
```

everything is ok, except the use of the enum. If I would do d.anyOtherField = someValue the query does compile. If I put the (correct) enum name there it does not.

Mapping:

```
package be.ejb.model.entity.dossier;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document {
    @Column(name = "T_I_TYA", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AttachmentType attachmentType;

    /* other fields etc */

}

package be.ejb.model.entity.admin.option;

public enum AttachmentType {
    REPORT;
}
```

The error i'm getting:

```
unknown identification variable [be]. The FROM clause of the query does not declare an identification variable [be]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.. 
Forgot to include the "AttachmentType" after the package declaration..